# Floating point problems in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some code below which loops a review and vocab document for a naive bayes classifier. The result is giving a 0, so i think there is a problem in the format of result.

```
%Loop the termdoc to find the word no.
    for k = 1: dlength 
        %Sum the records for that number
        if wordCount == d(k,1)
            result = result * ((sum(d(k,:)))-d(k,1))/n;
        end 
    end
end
%Multiply by the probability d/a
result = result * 0.5;
```

I have debugged the code, and all the right values are being stored in result, they seem to be rounding down maybe, im not too sure what matlabs doin here

Comment: If the initialization of `result` or only one of your terms `((sum(d(k,:)))-d(k,1))` is null, then the result will be null. Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possibility of an underflow. You are multiplying many numbers together, if each of them is less than 1, then the product may be less than realmin, therefore zero.

Logging the product may be the right thing to do, as then you will work with the sum of logs, which will not underflow.

If not that then you have not given sufficient information to make a better guess.

Comment: How would i go about logging the results? i think this is the way to go!

Comment: How would you go about logging it? There is a log function in matlab. Use it. What is the log of a product of numbers?

Comment: if wordCount == d(k,1)
            s = ((sum(d(k,:)))-d(k,1));
            if(s > 0)
                result = result * log(s/n);
                result
            end
        end

still gives 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the initial value of `result`?

What does this return?

```
I = (d(:,1) == wordCount);
values = sum(d,2) - d(:,1);
result = prod(values(I)/n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another point might be the precission of `double`

for `(sum(d(k,:)))-d(k,1)` if the entries `d(k,i >1)` are < `eps(d(k,1))` (value of the least significant digit in `d(k,1)` which can be *much* larger than realmin) they will not contribute to the sum making `(sum(d(k,:)))-d(k,1) = 0`